# Creating an instance of a class and adding it to a map. Java

Tags: java, class, dictionary, instance

Okay, lets say I have two classes. A customer and a shop.

```
  // In the class customer, I have 3 instance variables. 
  private String aFullName; 
  private String address;
  private char age; 

 // Then in the constructor, I have initialised these too:
 this.aFullName = fullName; 
 this.address = anAddress;
 this.age = anAge;

 //In my second class then, the shop...
 //I only have one variable where I've referenced a map: 
 private Map<String, Customer> customers;

//My constructor:
public Shop()
{
super();
customers = new HashMap<>()
}
```

**MY QUESTION IS:**

In the shop class, I have to create a method called addCustomer which takes 4 arguments. It will first create an instance of a customer and then add it my map called customers.

*The arguments cannot change, my problem is I'm confused as to how to create an instance when the arguments in the method and the variables in the customer class are different*

```
public void addCustomer(String memNo, String name, String address, char ageCat)
// where memNo is going to be the key.
```

How do I create an instance and add it to the map referenced by customers with memNo as the key?

Then, if I am testing this method, I should be able to add customers to the map but using this method addCustomer

Thank you

Comment: `this.customers.put(memNo, new Customer(name,address,ageCat))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by simply creating a method addCustomer with the 4 parameters and then inside of that method **instantiate** a new Customer object and **put** it in the map with the relevant **key**.

```java
public void addCustomer(String memNo, String name, String address, char ageCat) {
    customers.put(memNo, new Customer(name, address, ageCat);
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! Makes sense, I was trying to do it in 2 seperate lines which is why it wasn't working. I was trying to do new Customer ( name, address, ageCat) then customers.put(memNo, Customer) ! Thanks again

Comment: No problem at all!

Comment: I actually have another question. I'm now trying to print the map out. In the customer class I have a method called     public String toString() which is something likereturn (this.getName() + " " + this.getAddress() etc. 
My method in the shop class must use this method toString() to print out all of the customers. So far I have this:   public void printSkaters() { for (String eachCustomer : skaters.keySet()) { System.out.println(toString()); } } but my results are displayed like this:IceRink@67c8ebf
IceRink@67c8ebf
IceRink@67c8ebf 
rather than in a line with the correct names etc?

Comment: @ShanNicole You're calling System.out.println(toString()) when you mean to call eachCustomer.toString().

Comment: I tried this and it only prints their memNo rather than their name, address and age. I only need it to print their name, address and age as this is the only outputs in the toString() methods. I tried customers.toString() but it printed the whole map three times including the memNo :-(

Comment: Yeah so you're going to want to use values() instead of keySet().

Comment: Then make sure that Customer override toString()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210165/discussion-between-shan-nicole-and-jason).